# Android app is crashing. Not sure why

Tags: java, android

I apologize if this error/issue is too trivial. I have zero experience developing android apps so I am attempting to go through one of the [codepath](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki) tutorials, specifically [this one](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1lCFvYa3997wIUf7lwhbk7T8fblLBo4wjq_VxROWl4vs/edit#slide=id.gf45d6347_3_119), I'm at slide 11.

Here is the java:

package com.example.simpletodo;

```
package com.example.simpletodo;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TodoActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    ListView lvItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        items.add("First Item");
        items.add("Second Item");
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.todo, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TodoActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etNewITem"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNewITem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter new item" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app appears to be crashing at java line #22 `lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);`

Any advice is appreciated. I'm a php guy, so I'm not used to verbose code (learning) and how to debug a compiled program. Thanks!

Error messages from logcat:

```
02-06 16:29:31.563: W/dalvikvm(18897): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d39700)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simpletodo/com.example.simpletodo.TodoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at com.example.simpletodo.TodoActivity.onCreate(TodoActivity.java:21)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
02-06 16:29:31.563: E/AndroidRuntime(18897):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where do you create your ArrayList<String> items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never initialize the items variable, this causes you to get a null pointer exception when you try to set the adapter up because items is null.

do this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);
// initialize
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
// add content
        items.add("First Item");
        items.add("Second Item");

        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    }
```

You can see the error here in your logcat:

```
...
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 02-06 16:26:55.038: E/AndroidRuntime(17822): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330) 02-06 16:26:55.038: E/AndroidRuntime(17822): at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:470) 02-06 16:26:55.038: E/AndroidRuntime(17822): at com.example.simpletodo.TodoActivity.onCreate(TodoActivity.java:22) 02-06 ....
```

This tells you that at a `NullPointerException` occurred at `TodoActivity` line 22.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I knew it was stupid simple. Thanks. I should have known you have to instantiate before you can assign.

Comment: Nah, easy mistake when changing languages.  They're all so different.

Comment: Important thing to take away is how to read your log cat.  IT will tell you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We cant know the issue until you add your  log cat, but I did spot the following:

You add your items to the array before there's anything in them, fix it like this

```
    items.add("First Item");
    items.add("Second Item");
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Comment: It is not a problem. Probably the crush is caused by not creating the list. (new ArrayList<String>())

Answer (score -1):

Your problem in ArrrayAdapter

```
  items.add("First Item");
items.add("Second Item");
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```